# Issue while installing gcc-4.8.1 in Fedora 19

Tags: gcc, fedora

As per the installation instruction given on the gcc wiki site- http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC,

```
tar xvzf gcc-4.8.1.tar.gz
cd gcc-4.8.1
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.8.1 
make
make install
```

I was trying to install gcc in my laptop. But, I am getting the below error while installing just after entering the configure command.

```
checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln works... yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for libatomic support... yes
checking for libitm support... yes
checking for libsanitizer support... yes
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/home/fedora-19/Downloads/objdir':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

And after entering the make command below error is being displayed.

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Please guide on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an easiest way to install gcc on Fedora 19.
Did you try with yum ? With something like `sudo yum install gcc`

Your error means that the makefile which must be generated during the configure command doesn't exist because you don't have any c compiler. You can see details on the config.log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute following command to install GCC compiler in fedora:

yum install gcc

After executing this, it shows you a Total size and Total download size.

Or download gcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64 package from web and execute:

rpm -ivh gcc-4.4.7-3.el6.x86_64*

It may work.

Answer (score -1):

This solves the problem,

```
$PWD/../configure

make

make install
```